# Closed form for sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to get a closed form expression for,
$$\sum_{j=0}^i{i\choose j}.$$

Would welcome any guidance on this.

Comment: Try it for some small values of $i$ like $0,1,2,3,4$

Comment: It is $2^i$. See below the hint.

Comment: The binomial theorem says that $$(a+b)^i = \sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j}a^jb^{i-j} ~: ~i \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$$  Set $a = 1 = b$ and see where this leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinatorial argument:

Take a set with $i$ elements.  We want to count the number of possible subsets.

On one hand, this count is the number of subsets with 0 elements + number of subsets with 1 element +...:

$${i \choose 0}+{i \choose 1}+...+{i \choose i}.$$

On the other hand, we can count using the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product); to form a generic subset, there are 2 ways to treat the first element (include or exclude it in the subset), 2 ways to treat the second element (include or exclude it), ...:

$$\underbrace{2\times 2\times...\times 2}_{i \text{ times}}=2^i.$$

The two counts are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Remember that

$$ (a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} a^i b^{n-i} $$

What if $a=b=1$?